# elastisticsearch full text search with postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql, elasticsearch

Elasticsearch version 7.0.1
PostgreSQL 10.9 
openJDK 11

I want to get data using full text search of Elasticsearch from PostgreSQL database,how can I do it , anyone know about Elasticsearch? have any ideas for that?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this directly;
You can try using logStash to inject your PostgreSQL data to Elastisearch and then ask Elasticsaearch directly.

Here you can find full solution; https://medium.com/@erangadulshan.14/pushing-relational-data-to-elasticsearch-using-logstash-jdbc-input-plugin-48af81ed1000